# How to rebind C-r (undo-tree-redo) in Emacs with evil-mode?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, evil-mode

So I was wondering, how would I remap `C-r` when I am using `evil-mode`?

When I run `C-h k C-r`, I am told that `C-r` is bound in the `undo-tree-map` mapping.

So, I have tried to unbind it like so:

```
(define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-r") nil)
```

However, when I do `C-h k C-r`, I am yet again told that

```
C-r runs the command undo-tree-redo ...
```

So, how would I rebind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like there is a bug in Emacs where it does not tell you which mapping is mapping `C-r` to `undo-tree-redo`.

It seems like it's a bug in how emacs reports which file/mode/map defines a binding, when many bindings bind to the same function.

Nevertheless, the issue is with `evil-mode` doing the binding.

To rebind `C-r` to something else, try instead:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-r") 'evil-scroll-line-up)
```

Voila!

Comment: It is probably a `remap` situation in `undo-tree.el`, and you could word-search for that in the library and see all the functions that get remapped.  One of those functions that gets remapped is probably set by another library to be `C-r`.  Without activating `undo-tree-mode`, you could do a `M-x describe-key` to see which function is normally bound to `C-r` in your setup before said `minor-mode` gets turned on.